# Unable to get angularjs datepicker model value in js file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There are 2 date pickers in my application,

```
<div class= "row" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div moment-picker="ctrl.input" format="{{ctrl.format}}" >
   <input class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.input" ng-model-      options="{          updateOn: 'blur' }"
             placeholder="Select a start date...">
             </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">    
              <div moment-picker="ctrl.ionput"
         format="{{ctrl.format}}" >
        <input class="form-control"
             ng-model="ctrl.ionput"
             ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
             placeholder="Select a end date...">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to get value of these datepickers in my .js file to do HTTP call,

Tried with $scope.input and $scope.ctrl.input but unable to get values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to do an http request from controller, I believe its a form. According to the best practices, the approach given below is preferable.

The html should be like

```
<form ng-init="obj={}" ng-submit="doSubmit(obj)">
   <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="obj.name">
   <input type="date" placeholder="Date" ng-model="obj.date">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The controller should be like

```
angular.module('yourapp').controller('yourCtrl',['$scope','yourFactory',function($scope,yourFactory){
  $scope.doSubmit = function(data){
     yourFactory.submitForm(data).then(function(res){alert("Successfully   submitted the form");
     },function(err){
        alert("Error submitting form");
     });
   }
}]);
```

and then the `$http` call in factory.

So, according to me, if you use this approach, then you will easily be able to get in your controller that too using the best practices.

Comment: Thank you for the response, problem was both form and date picker were in different controller. After putting in same controller I was able to acess. Followed above design to get value in my js file.